# ipdb and unknown output

Tags: python, pdb, ipdb

I'm getting an output that I personally can't interpret when using IPDB. Does anyone know what this is or what it's called so I can do some further reading and learn what's going on.

Right now I'm not even sure what to google.
[image]

Comment: It is `ipdb`'s coloring, using [escapde-codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors), which your terminal is not displaying correctly. Is it `cmd` you're using?

Comment: Yes, default Windows 7 shell

Answer (score 0):

You might be bitten by the following issue: https://github.com/gotcha/ipdb/issues/31

A fix has been released in [ipdb 0.8.1](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipdb/0.8.1)